# matplotlib: grouping error bars for each x-axes tick

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to use matplotlib to plot error bars but have a slightly different requirements. So, the setup is as follows:

I have 3 different methods that I am comparing across 10 different parameter setting. So, on the y-axes I have the model fitting errors as given by the 3 methods and on the x-axes, I have the different parameter settings.

So, for each parameter setting, I would like to get 3 error bar plots corresponding to the three methods. Ideally, I would like to plot the 95% confidence interval and also the minimum and maximum for each method for each parameter setting.

Some example data can be simulated as:

```
parameters = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
mean_1 = [10.1, 12.1, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 11.8, 28.5]
std_1 = [2.6, 5.7, 4.3, 8.5, 11.8, 5.3, 2.5]

mean_2 = [10.1, 12.1, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 11.8, 28.5]
std_1 = [2.6, 5.7, 4.3, 8.5, 11.8, 5.3, 2.5]

mean_3 = [10.1, 12.1, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 11.8, 28.5]
std_3 = [2.6, 5.7, 4.3, 8.5, 11.8, 5.3, 2.5]
```

I have kept the values same as it does not change anything from the plotting point of view. I see matplotlib.errorbar method but I do not know how to extend it for multiple methods over one single x-axes value as I have in my case. Additionally, I am not sure how to add the `[min, max]` markers for each of the methods.

Comment: have a look at the [documentation of errorbar](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html)!

Comment: None of those examples does what the question asks... what have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your `parameters` list as x axis, `mean_1` as y value and `std_1` as errors you can plot an errorbar chart with

```
pylab.errorbar(parameters, mean_1, yerr=std_1, fmt='bo')
```

In case the error bars are not symmetric, i.e. you have `lower_err` and `upper_err`, the statement reads

```
pylab.errorbar(parameters, mean_1, yerr=[lower_err, upper_err], fmt='bo')
```

The same works with keyword `xerr` for errors in x direction, which is now hopefully self-explanatory.
To show several (in your case 3) different datasets, you can go the following way:

```
# import pylab and numpy
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

# define datasets
parameters = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
mean_1 = [10.1, 12.1, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 11.8, 28.5]
std_1 = [2.6, 5.7, 4.3, 8.5, 11.8, 5.3, 2.5]

mean_2 = [10.1, 12.1, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 11.8, 28.5]
std_2 = [2.6, 5.7, 4.3, 8.5, 11.8, 5.3, 2.5]

mean_3 = [10.1, 12.1, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 11.8, 28.5]
std_3 = [2.6, 5.7, 4.3, 8.5, 11.8, 5.3, 2.5]


# here comes the plotting;
# to achieve a grouping, two things are extra here: 
# 1. Don't use line plot but circular markers and different marker color
# 2. slightly displace the datasets in x direction to avoid overlap 
#    and create visual grouping
pl.errorbar(np.array(parameters)-0.01, mean_1, yerr=std_1, fmt='bo')
pl.errorbar(parameters, mean_2, yerr=std_2, fmt='go')
pl.errorbar(np.array(parameters)+0.01, mean_3, yerr=std_3, fmt='ro')
pl.show()
```

This is about pylab.errorbar, where you have to give the errors explicitly. An alternative approach is to use [pylab.boxplot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html) and to prodice a boxplot for each model, but therefore I guess I'll need the full distribution per model per parameter instead of just mean and std.