# Grouped errorbar with array of strings as data points

Tags: matplotlib, errorbar

I have different measurements from two+ sensors. I want to compare the performance of each sensor for each measurement with errorbars (mean and std). I have no problems creating and formatting a standard errorbar plot for one y (sensor) and yerr per data point (measurement). But i'm trying to create a plot like this:

[image: Grouped Error Bar]

I can neither find the option to do this in the matplotlib documentation nor when i google it or search this site. The closest i found was this thread:
[matplotlib: grouping error bars for each x-axes tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475838/matplotlib-grouping-error-bars-for-each-x-axes-tick)

But this solution doesn't work for me since my datapoints aren't numbers but a pandas dataframe index of strings.

Comment: At the end the strings are just mapped to numbers. So you may position your bars at 0,1,3,4 (leave 2 out for the spacing).

Comment: Thank you yes i just wanted to post my own answer i finally found the solution you describe in the Matplotlib documentation after all

Comment: Sure, go ahead and answer your question; it might be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution in the Matplotlib documentation after all. Here's the link for people who might have the same question:
[A bar plot with errorbars and height labels on individual bars.](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html)